How do I convert this string 'April 9, 2013' into the format 'dd-mm-yyyy' in MySQL
I have been trying to convert a column consisting of dates in the format 'April 9, 2013' into the format '%d/%m/%Y' which would result in '09-04-2013'.
I have tried using the STR_TO_DATE function and it results in null values.
I’m thinking I separate the date, month and year into columns then combine them after converting them to integers but I think there’s an easier way of doing it.
Please help me out

Delete it i guess, but yeah its basically this :
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('April 9, 2013', '%M %e, %Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') AS formatted_date;

Please don't! You should update your table to store your date strings as proper DATEs - UPDATE your_table SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y'); so they are properly formatted in yyyy-mm-dd format. Then change the datatype to DATE. This uses less storage space and can be sorted in a meaningful way. Then you can convert to whatever format you want on output - SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM your_table;. Or even better, leave things like date formatting to the client application.

@user1191247 is correct, I would recommend you post that as an answer :-)

Please don't! You should update your table to store your date strings as proper DATEs.
your_table



id
date_col




1
September 29, 2012


2
April 9, 2013


3
March 3, 2015


4
December 19, 2012



With the dates stored as strings we cannot sort them in any meaningful way (without transforming them first).
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY date_col ASC;

Outputs



id
date_col




2
April 9, 2013


4
December 19, 2012


3
March 3, 2015


1
September 29, 2012



That's not much use to anyone. Assuming these are stored in a VARCHAR column, December 19, 2012 will use 18 bytes. Stored as data type DATE it will be 3 bytes.
First reformat the content of the date_col:
UPDATE your_table SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%M %e, %Y');

Then change the data type:
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN date_col DATE NOT NULL;

your_table



id
date_col




1
2012-09-29


2
2013-04-09


3
2015-03-03


4
2012-12-19



Now this can be easily formatted and or sorted:
SELECT id, date_col, DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dt
FROM your_table
ORDER BY date_col ASC;

Outputs



id
date_col
dt




1
2012-09-29
29-09-2012


4
2012-12-19
19-12-2012


2
2013-04-09
09-04-2013


3
2015-03-03
03-03-2015



Here's a db<>fiddle.
